# Laravel creating a request instance with a url string

Tags: laravel, symfony

I am looking to create a request instance in Laravel using a url string. I have this piece of code which does the job, URL segments is wrong.

```
$previous_request = app('request')->create($previous_url);
```

The following is the URL segments from the manually created request.

```
array:7 [▼
  0 => "developments"
  1 => "tour"
  2 => "public"
  3 => "en"
  4 => "admin"
  5 => "products"
  6 => "items"
]
```

The following is the example of the request provided from Laravel itself.

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "en"
  1 => "admin"
  2 => "products"
  3 => "items"
]
```

Anyone have done similar things before and is able to help out?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is located in the referrer in the request's header.

```
$referer = $request->header('referer');
```

or

```
$referer = Request::server('HTTP_REFERER');
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! However, I am looking to create a new request instance, I do have access to the previous url string. My issue is just that the newly create request instance does not have the correct baseUrl attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I did :

```
$request = new Request; 
$request->myData = $myData;
// do whatever you want to do with your Request object
```